# Cannot find a handler of type EndpointResolver in AWSSDKS3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-s3-client

This is my issue:
I am updating AWS S3 nuget package from  3.7.1.2 to 3.7.101.25
Project details:
I have API that calls Class Library in which i am creating a AmazonS3Client. In version "3.7.1.2", its working fine. But in 3.7.101.25, i am getting below error.
Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 
Message=Cannot find a handler of type EndpointResolver 
Source=AWSSDK.Core
```

Code:

```
var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
     MaxErrorRetry = maxRetryAttempts,
     Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(requestTimeoutInSecond),
     ServiceURL = serviceURL
    }
     s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(key, secret, amazonS3Config);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue where AWS looks like they opened up a ticket and resolved the issue. My issue was with AmazonKinesisClient but the same error.

https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/issues/267 - same exception but for the AmazonDynamoDBClient.

This was resolved by installing the package **AWSXRayRecorder.Handlers.AwsSdk v2.11.0**

Comment: I had a similar issue but fixed it by upgrading from 2.8.3 to 2.12.0.